Continuous bijective map $\mathbb{R}^2\to S^2$
Is there any continuous bijective function $\mathbb{R}^2\to S^2$?
I want to prove that such map does not exist, however, I cannot use the closed map lemma as $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not compact. I was looking for some result like "continuous bijective $\Rightarrow$ homeomorphism", or maybe something like "the image of a non compact space under a continuous bijective function is non compact".
Any hint? Thanks in advance

Invariance of domain theorem should work to show there exists no such function.
